# Environment variable to compile with Qt4 or Qt5?

Tags: ubuntu, qt4, qt5

Currently in my ubuntu setup, if I want to compile a project with Qt5, I simply run `qmake && make`. And if I want to compile with Qt4, I do `/usr/share/qt4/bin/qmake && make`

But I have a large project where the qmake sequences are shrouded in scripts. It runs only with Qt4 but running the scripts directly uses the default, which is Qt5. Is there an environment variable (or some other method) I can set to tell the script to use Qt4 instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The *qtchooser* tool was written for this purpose: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/qtchooser.1.html

Answer (score 0):

From reading its man page, I don't see how qtchooser works. Instead I simply preface my command with QT_SELECT=qt4, for instance `QT_SELECT=qt4 qtcreator .`